# How would you say, "You stole my heart"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

There's an English idiom, "You stole my heart", which means that someone has won our love or affection. Is there a similar idiom in French? Would the literal translation, *Tu as volé mon coeur*, be idiomatic?

Comment: Je remplacerais _voler_ par _ravir_: _Tu me ravis le cœur_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour exprimer l'idée de « je suis folle de toi » ou « je suis follement amoureuse de toi » :

> Mon cœur ne bat que pour toi.
>
> Mon cœur t'appartient à jamais.
>
> Tu as pris la clé de mon cœur.
>
> Tu as volé mon cœur.
>
> Tu me fais craquer.
>
> Je t'aime de tout mon cœur.
>
> Je t'aime à la folie.
>
> Je suis bleue/éprise/dingue de toi.

Comment: Merci. Mais sont-elles les phrases "Tu as volé mon cœur" et "Tu as pris la clé de mon cœur" très idiomatique? Nous avons les mêmes phrases en anglais. Je suis inquiet qu'ils ne soient que des traductions des phrases anglaises.

Comment: @ktm5124 Ne t'inquiète pas, ce n’est pas parce qu’on utilise la même expression en anglais que c’est une mauvaise traduction littérale. Personnellement, je dit « tu as pris mon cœur », mais « tu as volé mon cœur », ça n'en reste pas moins, elle aussi, une expression couramment employée dans le cadre d'une relation amoureuse. By the by, I’m not "Ms"! ;)

Comment: J'ai un doute concernant *Je suis bleu de toi*...

Comment: *Je suis bleu de toi* est à mon sens un belgicisme. Cela signifie effectivement "être raide dingue de quelqu'un"... Peut-être rencontre-t-on aussi l'expression dans le Nord de la France ?

Comment: @Greg Doctors visiting our hospital come from all over Europe, so I must have picked this "blue" usage from a Belgian somewhere along the way. Interesting find!

Comment: Actually, I must have used this phrase since my childhood, and it's just thanks to this thread that I have realized it is only a Belgian phrase ! In Brussels downtown, you will even find a jewelry store named *Bleu de toi*,  so you can imagine how common it is here. Another local Belgian use is *un bleu*, which is a university student that has not gone (yet) through some initiation rituals organized by senior students. But I have no clue if there is a link with the other local use of *bleu*.

Comment: @Greg Japanese might have something in common with another use of "blue" you mentioned. We use "青二才 {blue and two years old}" or "尻が青い {ass is blue}" to mean "someone is still wet behind the ears" or "**green**horn" in English. Or "**blanc**-bec" in French.

Answer (score 1):

"tu m'as volé mon coeur" peut se dire, sans que ça semble une traduction maladroite. En revanche je n'ai jamais entendu "Je suis bleu(e) de toi"! peut -être n'ai-je jamais suscité un tel émoi?

Comment: *Je suis bleu de toi* s'entend beaucoup en Belgique, cela semble être un belgicisme.